# Limit of $(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})...(1+\frac{1}{2^n})$ as $n \to \infty$ and the rationality of the answer

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

What is the Limit of $(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})...(1+\frac{1}{2^n})$ at n = $\infty$?

At first I think it is divergent but it is surely convergent to something between $2$ and $3$. More exactly it is between $2.3$ to $2.4$. something about $2.38$. but I don't know how to find its limit. What can we say about rationality of the answer? (Is it rational or irrational?)

My question is made of two parts. first finding the limit and second, discussing about its rationality.

Comment: you should use logarithms

Comment: @kingW3 My first part of the question is the same but the second part (rationality) is not the same. What can we say about the rationality?

Comment: I would say it is almost certainly irrational but that is very hard to prove.  There are so few rationals that you don't hit them by accident.